# Help Orthogonal trajectory

Tags: calculus

Find orthogonal trajectory to the family of curves $$ y=(x-c)^2$$

having trouble with this question because to find $c$ you are stuck with $\pm y$

Comment: How so? $y$ can only be nonnegative.

Comment: why? if we take square root on both sides wouldnt it be +-?

Comment: $(x-c)^2$ is nonnegative for all $x$. There is no negative value of $y$ for which this equation can be satisfied.